# How do I hide the "Get CRM for Outlook" notification in Dynamics CRM 2011 for specific user accounts?

Tags: notifications, crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have about 4 guys sharing a common CAL to a CRM 2011 installation. I need to hide the "get CRM for Outlook" notification for this common user account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CRM Client >> Settings >> Administation >> System Settings >> Outlook tab >>` bottom option - `Get the Outlook Client` message set to off

Comment: @novicecrm - can you please tick the V in the left of my answer?